# How can LIKE '%...' seek on an index?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, wildcard, sql-execution-plan, sql-like

I would expect these two `SELECT`s to have the same execution plan and performance. Since there is a leading wildcard on the `LIKE`, I expect an index scan. When I run this and look at the plans, the first `SELECT` behaves as expected (with a scan). But the second `SELECT` plan shows an index seek, and runs 20 times faster.

Code:

```
-- Uses index scan, as expected:
SELECT 1
    FROM AccountAction
    WHERE AccountNumber LIKE '%441025586401'

-- Uses index seek somehow, and runs much faster:
declare @empty VARCHAR(30) = ''
SELECT 1
    FROM AccountAction
    WHERE AccountNumber LIKE '%441025586401' + @empty
```

Question:

How does SQL Server use an index seek when the pattern starts with a wildcard?

Bonus question:

Why does concatenating an empty string change/improve the execution plan?

Details:

- There is a non-clustered index on `Accounts.AccountNumber`
- There are other indexes, but both the seek and the scan are on *this* index.
- The `Accounts.AccountNumber` column is a nullable `varchar(30)`
- The server is SQL Server 2012

Table and index definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE [updatable].[AccountAction](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AccountNumber] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Utility] [varchar](9) NOT NULL,
    [SomeData1] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [SomeData2] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [SomeData3] [money] NULL,
    --...
    [Created] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Account] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_updatable_AccountAction_AccountNumber_UtilityCode_ActionTypeCd] ON [updatable].[AccountAction]
(
    [AccountNumber] ASC,
    [Utility] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([SomeData1], [SomeData2], [SomeData3]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [CIX_Account] ON [updatable].[AccountAction]
(
    [Created] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

NOTE:
Here is the *actual* execution plan for the two queries. The names of the objects differ slightly from the code above because I was trying to keep the question simple.

[image: The two execution plans.]

Comment: is there difference in actual execution or only in estimation plans?

Comment: @GordonLinoff SQL Server 2012's version number is 11, 2008 R2: 10.5, 2008: 10, etc.

Comment: I don't know how important it could be, but the queries that you actually ran were `LIKE '%441025586401%'`, with a wildcard at the beggining and end

Comment: Could be parameter sniffing and the estimated plan might not realize how bad that seek might actually be. What happens if you use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on the query (or clear out the plan cache)?

Comment: @RomanPekar These are acutal execution plans.

Comment: You've not posted the code for the index that's actually being used. Looks like it's seeking on an index on the AccountAction (an index named IX_updateable_Accou...). This isn't any of the indexes that you've posted nor is it on the table

Comment: @Lamak I took trailing wildcards out for simplicity but the results are unchanged by the trailing wildcard.

Comment: Also please be sure to measure `SET STATISTICS TIME ON;` and `SET STATISTICS IO ON;` so that you can see whether the seek or scan is actually better. Do *not* rely solely on the 96% and 4% figures to give you any indication about actual performance - these numbers are largely meaningless on their own.

Comment: Also the table in use is AccountAction or Account? Help us match the DDL you included with the plans. Could you post the actual execition plans somewhere?

Comment: I've tried these queries on my SQL 2008 R2. If I see execution plan, it shows that second one SHOULD run faster, like 5% to 95%. Actual execution is much closer, but one with @empty variable still faster...

Comment: My hunch is that in your attempts to obfuscate you've left out some important details that would indicate why you get a seek.

Comment: @swasheck, no, it's as simple as that - I've just created table, populated it with rows and these two queries shows different plans

Comment: @swasheck . . . Thank you for the version information.  That's why I asked.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no worries. TMYK.

Comment: @RomanPekar did you run both queries with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`?

Comment: @swasheck it doesn't matter. Actually, I see now that one with empty variableruns longer, I think i was mistaken.

Comment: @pants I was wondering if you would post the actual queries. Perhaps even post a link on SQLFiddle with your structure and some sample data.

Comment: With swasheck's OPTION(RECOMPILE) and AaronBertrand's STATISTICS TIME and STATISTICS IO on, it changes to using index scans for both queries. Their 'costs' are both 50% of the batch and their cpu times are very close.

Comment: pants: actually @AaronBertrand recommended that first :D. So look into the parameter sniffing thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These tests (database AdventureWorks2008R2) shows what happens:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET STATISTICS IO ON;

PRINT 'Test #1';
SELECT  p.BusinessEntityID, p.LastName
FROM    Person.Person p
WHERE   p.LastName LIKE '%be%';

PRINT 'Test #2';
DECLARE @Pattern NVARCHAR(50);
SET @Pattern=N'%be%';
SELECT  p.BusinessEntityID, p.LastName
FROM    Person.Person p
WHERE   p.LastName LIKE @Pattern;

SET STATISTICS IO OFF;
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

Results:

```
Test #1
Table 'Person'. Scan count 1, logical reads 106
Test #2
Table 'Person'. Scan count 1, logical reads 106
```

The results from `SET STATISTICS IO` shows that LIO are the **same**.
But the execution plans are quite different:
[image]

In the first test, SQL Server uses an `Index Scan` explicit but in the second test SQL Server uses an `Index Seek` which is an `Index Seek - range scan`. In the last case SQL Server uses a `Compute Scalar` operator to generate these values

```
[Expr1005] = Scalar Operator(LikeRangeStart([@Pattern])), 
[Expr1006] = Scalar Operator(LikeRangeEnd([@Pattern])), 
[Expr1007] = Scalar Operator(LikeRangeInfo([@Pattern]))
```

and, the `Index Seek` operator use an `Seek Predicate` (optimized) for a `range scan` (`LastName > LikeRangeStart AND LastName < LikeRangeEnd`) plus another unoptimized `Predicate` (`LastName LIKE @pattern`).

> How can LIKE '%...' seek on an index?

**My answer: it isn't a "real" `Index Seek`. It's a `Index Seek - range scan` which, in this case, has the same performance like `Index Scan`.**

Please see, also, the difference between `Index Seek` and `Index Scan` (similar debate):
[So…is it a Seek or a Scan?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/02/16/so-is-it-a-seek-or-a-scan.aspx).

**Edit 1:** The execution plan for `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` (see Aaron's recommendation please) shows, also, an `Index Scan` (instead of `Index Seek`):
[image]